# Apache invisible URL Rewrite to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use URL Rewrite to rewrite all requests on my domain to a subdirectory. But the visitor hould not see, that it is a subdirectory. I tried a view things, but nothing worked really good. Can you help me? In this subdirectory is also a .htaccess file and this file shouldn't be ignored by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*) sub-directory/$1 [L]
```